# Size limits on Get/POST parameters?

Tags: g-wan

I noticed once the length of a GET parameter is longer than 400 bytes, or 2000 bytes for a POST parameter, G-WAN returns 400 error. Is there any way to increase the limits?

And when I try the csp_entity.html, I keep get 400 error as well for the file size less than the entity size limit. (413 error for the exceeding files, which is expected)

Note: the latest G-WAN in ubuntu 12.10.

Comment: MAX_ENTITY_SIZE should fix this issue. But when I try it it's not working right. my test on 32 bit G-WAN version you cannot change the limit. On 64 bit G-WAN you can change the limit but you will get 404 error when you reach around 4000 bytes. I already sent test cases to Pierre to replicate this issue.

Answer (score 1):

Two examples are on their way, one with streaming and one without. They will both serve the purpose of showing how to proceed and to test the implementation.

Everyone having the same codebase, reporting issues (if any) will be easier.

Note that v4.25 has been shipped this morning. It does the same things done by v4.24, but v4.25 corrects some compiler optimizations that have generated bugs for a few users on some platforms (empty files, empty dates).

Comment: I just tried v4.25, while got such error in trace:  
  
Sat Jan 26 08:10:12 2013 GMT] loaded Connection Handler main.c      18.24 KiB   MD5:7e70ad45-66cc7ea0-6b93646b-79b7dd33   
  
[Sat Jan 26 08:10:14 2013 GMT] * setup: (1/4) No such file or directory

Comment: Anyway I can get an older version as 4.25 cannot start in my box.